# Default to --Non-Interactive

Tags: svn

Is there any way to have all svn commands default to act as though they were passed the --non-interactive parameter? We have some wrapper executables that perform a series of svn commands that hang whenever they hit a conflict since upgrading the subversion client to version 1.5.1 due to interactive conflict resolution.

Ideally I would like this to simply default to postpone. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is a global or per-user setting inside the subversion config files

your switch is called:

```
interactive-conflicts = [yes | no]
```

default is 'yes'

look [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config) for more info.

Comment: Yes this is a very dumb question indeed, as the link will tell you all details: short summary: unix: /etc/subversion ~/.subversion  on windows: in Registry [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Config\ and %APPDATA%\Subversion

Comment: This setting seems to only apply to conflicts (which may be fine for Phillip), but doesn't seem to work to suppress prompting for a user's client certificate (where the --non-interactive option will).  Just a thought...

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with just explicitly passing --Non-Interactive in your wrapper executables?

Comment: This might not be the desired behavior for all users and not all users are on the 1.5.1 client.